# Integrate Wazuh with Yara failed

Tags: yara, wazuh

I configured agent.conf with the following:

```
 <agent_config>
    <!-- File integrity monitoring -->
    <syscheck>
        <disabled>no</disabled>
        <!-- Frequency that syscheck is executed default every 12 hours -->
        <frequency>60</frequency>
        <scan_on_start>yes</scan_on_start>
        <!-- Directories to check  (perform all possible verifications) -->
        <directories>/etc,/usr/bin,/usr/sbin</directories>
        <directories>/bin,/sbin,/boot</directories>
        <directories check_all="yes" realtime="yes">/home</directories>
        <directories check_all="yes" realtime="yes">/root</directories>
        <alert_new_files>yes</alert_new_files>
        <!-- Files/directories to ignore -->
        <ignore>/etc/mtab</ignore>
        <ignore>/etc/hosts.deny</ignore>
        <ignore>/etc/mail/statistics</ignore>
        <ignore>/etc/random-seed</ignore>
        <ignore>/etc/random.seed</ignore>
        <ignore>/etc/adjtime</ignore>
        <ignore>/etc/httpd/logs</ignore>
        <ignore>/etc/utmpx</ignore>
        <ignore>/etc/wtmpx</ignore>
        <ignore>/etc/cups/certs</ignore>
        <ignore>/etc/dumpdates</ignore>
        <ignore>/etc/svc/volatile</ignore>
        <!-- File types to ignore -->
        <ignore type="sregex">.log$|.swp$</ignore>
        <!-- Check the file, but never compute the diff -->
        <nodiff>/etc/ssl/private.key</nodiff>
        <skip_nfs>yes</skip_nfs>
        <skip_dev>yes</skip_dev>
        <skip_proc>yes</skip_proc>
        <skip_sys>yes</skip_sys>
        <!-- Nice value for Syscheck process -->
        <process_priority>10</process_priority>
        <!-- Maximum output throughput -->
        <max_eps>100</max_eps>
        <!-- Database synchronization settings -->
        <synchronization>
            <enabled>yes</enabled>
            <interval>5m</interval>
            <max_interval>1h</max_interval>
            <max_eps>10</max_eps>
        </synchronization>
    </syscheck>
    <command>
        <name>yara</name>
        <executable>yara</executable>
        <extra-args>-yara_path /usr/local/bin -yara_rules /tmp/yara/rules/index.yar</extra-args>
        <timeout_allowed>no</timeout_allowed>
    </command>
    <active-response>
        <command>yara</command>
        <location>local</location>
        <rules_id>550,554</rules_id>
    </active-response>
</agent_config>
```

Yara is working if I run it manually via cmd.
FIM did detect the newly downloaded malicious file but the Wazuh active response is not working. There is no log found in active-response.log.

Here below is the `yara.sh` stored in `/var/ossec/active-response/bin` folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Wazuh - Yara active response
# Copyright (C) 2015-2022, Wazuh Inc.
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it
# and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public
# License (version 2) as published by the FSF - Free Software
# Foundation.
#------------------------- Gather parameters -------------------------#

# Static active response parameters
LOCAL=`dirname $0`

# Extra arguments
read -r INPUT_JSON
YARA_PATH=$(echo $INPUT_JSON | jg -r .parameters.extra_args[1])
YARA_RULES=$(echo $INPUT_JSON | jg -r .parameters.extra_args[3])
FILENAME=$(echo $INPUT_JSON | jq -r .parameters.alert.syscheck.path)
COMMAND=$(echo $INPUT_JSON | jq -r .command)

# Move to the active response folder
cd $LOCAL
cd ../

# Set LOG_FILE path
PWD=`pwd`
LOG_FILE="${PWD}/../logs/active-responses.log"

#----------------------- Analyze parameters -----------------------#

if [[ ! $YARA_PATH ]] || [[ ! $YARA_RULES ]]
then
  echo "wazuh-yara: ERROR - Yara active response error. Yara path and rules parameters are mandatory." >> ${LOG_FILE}
  exit
fi

#------------------------ Analyze command -------------------------#
if [ ${COMMAND} = "add" ]
then
  # Send control message to execd
  printf '{"version":1,"origin":{"name":"yara","module":"active-response"},"command":"check_keys", "parameters":{"keys":[]}}\n'

  read RESPONSE
  COMMAND2=$(echo $RESPONSE | jq -r .command)
  if [ ${COMMAND2} != "continue" ]
  then
    echo "wazuh-yara: INFO - Yara active response aborted." >> ${LOG_FILE}
    exit 1;
  fi
fi

#------------------------- Main workflow --------------------------#

# Execute Yara scan on the specified filename
yara_output="$("${YARA_PATH}"/yara -w -r "$YARA_RULES" "$FILENAME")"

if [[ $yara_output != "" ]]
then
  # Iterate every detected rule and append it to the LOG_FILE
  while read -r line; do
  echo "wazuh-yara: INFO - Scan result: $line" >> ${LOG_FILE}
  done <<< "$yara_output"
fi

exit 1;
```

Is there anything I missed out to configure?

Answer (score 0):

The `active-response` and the `command` configuration blocks cannot be in the `agent.conf` file as both configurations are part of the manager and therefore, they must be in the manager's `ossec.conf`. Apart from this change, you also need to modify the executable name as it must include the file extension (`.sh`).

```
<command>
    <name>yara</name>
    <executable>yara.sh</executable>
    <extra-args>-yara_path /usr/local/bin -yara_rules /tmp/yara/rules/index.yar</extra-args>
    <timeout_allowed>no</timeout_allowed>
</command>
<active-response>
    <command>yara</command>
    <location>local</location>
    <rules_id>550,554</rules_id>
</active-response>
```

Also, note that the `yara.sh` script must be in all the agents where you want to perform the Yara integration (in the agents' `/var/ossec/active-response/bin` folder).

Check that the file ownership and permissions are the proper ones, **750** and **root:wazuh**, respectively. `jq` also needs to be installed in all the agents.

If you still have problems, have a look at the manager's `ossec.log` file in order to find error logs o warnings. You can also enable the debug mode of the daemon in charge of active response to see more logs in the `ossec.log`. To do that, add the following line to the manager's `/var/ossec/etc/local_internal_options.conf` and restart the service:

```
execd.debug=2
```

Comment: I did set it in manager ossec.conf as well and tried again but still, it gives no result.The yara.sh file that I placed it in the agent /var/ossec/active-response/bin folder,I have already set the correct permission and ownership (root:ossec).I tried to hardcode and run ./yara.sh manually in order to execute yara on malicious file, the result were all populated into active-responses.log.But nothing happened when I simply created a new file in /home directory just to trigger yara.sh and run the hardcoded script.FIM works but not active response,it seems like the yara.sh file was not triggered.

Comment: Which Wazuh version are you using?

Comment: im currently using 4.2.5

Comment: So with 4.2.5, as you said, the ownership is root:ossec.

Comment: How do you execute the Yara scan manually? Could you paste the command and the output?

Comment: I have just seen this error in your yara.sh script


`# Extra arguments
read -r INPUT_JSON
YARA_PATH=$(echo $INPUT_JSON | jg -r .parameters.extra_args[1])
YARA_RULES=$(echo $INPUT_JSON | jg -r .parameters.extra_args[3])
FILENAME=$(echo $INPUT_JSON | jq -r .parameters.alert.syscheck.path)
COMMAND=$(echo $INPUT_JSON | jq -r .command)`


Note that `jg` is used instead of `jq`, could you confirm this error?

Comment: i have installed jq, but i get error - wazuh-execd: INFO: Active response command not present: 'active-response/bin/restart-ossec.sh'. Not using it on this system.